# Is there an online repository of audio lectures from JTS faculty?

Tags: product-recommendation, adult-learning

I am looking for an online archive of audio lectures from JTS faculty such as Rabbi Saul Lieberman and Rabbi Abraham Joshua Heschel. Does such a site exist?

Comment: If you ever come across such an archive kindly do good and post.

Comment: I got a TV interview Rabbi Heschel gave in 1971 shortly before his death from the public library years ago. Of course, it is not a scholarly lecture, but it was interesting.

Answer (score 1):

There is an online archive of audio lectures by *current* JTS faculty [available here](http://www.jtsa.edu/jts-torah-online?author=2862) a quick search does not turn up any results for content from the deceased faculty you specifically identify